# Mobile device does not shrink in width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a responsive website.  Basically when you resize the browser, things shift around and such.  Right now I have that portion working fine.

The problem though comes when I Load the page on my cell phone, the phone seems to load in 1024 pixels width no matter what.  Right now I forced my content to be 450 pixels wide, and that did not do the trick either.  Does this has something to do with the fact I am using max-width?  Can max-width tell the phone to load it in 1024 pixels?  If so how can I get around that, how do I tell the mobile devices to load the website in the size they are intended?

At this point in time I am not using any media queries because I have not gotten to the part where I require them, but I'm also wondering if this is the problem as well?  Do I absolutely must have media queries and lets say if its 720 pixels, I have to force every object to have max width of 720 pixels or it will not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the [`viewport` `<meta>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: I have added that meta tag, however that made the page not only shrink, but shrink beyond the set width of the page which is 450 pixels, how do I make the page be the set width?

Comment: I'm guessing this is where media queries come in play and I adjust rest of the site to those sizes?

Comment: @Bagzli A pretty typical strategy would be a media query which sets the content width to `100%` when the page width is below `450` or whatever you have by default.

Comment: Don't use 'maximum-scale=1' unless you have a really valid reason to do so. This will prevent users from zooming in using pinch-to-zoom. Read: http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho

Comment: @tomasz86 Assuming your site layout is done properly (a good font size, images are scaled up to fit the screen), not being able to zoom in and out improves the experience in my opinion.

Comment: I don't believe there exist any "proper" font-size. For me a 12px font-size may be enough but my grandmother may need a 24px font-size to be able to read the same text. You are always able to zoom in and out in desktop browsers and I can't see any reason why it should be different on mobile. Fortunately some mobile browsers (like Chrome) give options to override this setting.